# Why can not pass void to function with no parameters?

Tags: c++

Why does compiler not treat `return_nothing(return_nothing())` as `return_nothing(); return_nothing();` because the return type of `return_nothing()` is `void`?

```
void return_nothing() {}

int main()
{    
    return_nothing(return_nothing()); // compile error
}
```

Live: [Wanbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Ybd8xOnqAYWa9hKG)

Comment: `void` is not a value, but a type. You can't pass `int` as parameter too. And the type `void` has no possible values.

Comment: I would think it would treat it as `return_nothing(); return_nothing();` if anything, but you can't use a void return and you can't pass into a void parameter list. I think this is a justified case of a "WTF are you trying to do?" error message.

Comment: `return_nothing` takes nothing as parameter and returns nothing, but it is still something. So passing something as argument to something that takes nothing as argument is a compiler error.

Comment: @user4581301 I've changed it

Comment: It's so rare, and easily worked-around use case, that  I'd have a hard time justifying the extra parser complexity to handle it. Might as well just make it illegal and save writing and debugging code.

Comment: Actually I ask this question is because I met a compile error when I try to perform std::promise<R>::set_value(f()); in a template. When the passing f() return type is void, the promise set_value changes to accept nothing.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate in C where functions taking no parameters are in fact declared with `void` in place of the parameter list: e.g. `void f(void)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are programming in C++, and in C++ a void-returning function cannot be used there, and your compiler is (at least an approximation) of the C++ language as described by the standard.

There are, in C++, no value of type `void`.  `void` is the type without a value.

Passing `void` to a function is illegal, as functions take values.

There is one minor exception: if you have an operation returning `void`, you can `return ooeratio_returning_void();` from another void-returning function.  This was done to make some template meta-programming easier.

The issue of "passing a void-returning function to a function expecting no arguments" is sometimes also a template metaprogramming issue, but it is a far rarer one.  You can usually work around it with only a bit of boilerplate.

Comment: Returning an expression of type `void` is always legal in a function whose return type is (possibly cv-qualified) `void`; no dependent types or templates required.

Comment: @t.c. really?  I thought it was template code only.  I wonder why?

Comment: @Yakk Yes, [\[stmt.return\]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#2). I suspect that allowing it is definitely for the benefit of templates, but once you've done that, there's not much gain from banning it for non-templates.